# how to create JSpinner alike input field?

Tags: android

[image]

I'm beginner in android,
Please help me to create the JSpinner like input field.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: You should google for `android custom spinner`. But I guess it's much simpler than that. Simply assigning a rounded rect backround (as a shape drawable) should do the trick. And the button can have its own drawable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what jspinner looks like but it seems like you're looking for a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) . You can find a tutorial on usage [here](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html).

If that's not what you're looking for you can also search for custom spinners on GitHub ,the android open-source communities has a lot of libraries which will help you achieve what you want.